# ResourceNotFound: sbpl on roslaunch

Tags: ros, cmake, sbpl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From : https://github.com/sbpl/sbpl
Installed SBPL at /usr/local

tried :

```
mudit@mudit:$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

`Then:

```
$ roslaunch sbpl_lattice_planner move_base_sbpl_fake_localization_2.5cm.launch
```

Shows the following error :
ResourceNotFound: sbpl
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/mudit/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/kinetic/stacks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242999/resourcenotfound:-sbpl-on-roslaunch/) by [non-conventional_stuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/27818/non-conventional_stuff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-09-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-09-02**:
sbpl_lattice_planner probably expects sbpl to be installed in your catkin workspace as a ROS package so that it can find the motion primitives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The launch file of sbpl lattice planner was searching for sbpl by using find command which was further referencing the motion primitive file. By replacing the find command with absolute path for motion primitve file solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [non-conventional_stuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/27818/non-conventional_stuff/) with karma: 16 on 2016-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0